# Getting value from a map data structure

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, iteration

When I'm trying to print the value of a prop in the `Reactjs` code, I'm getting the following:

```
console.log(this.props.rec.get('data'));

 Map
    __altered: false
    __hash: undefined
    __ownerID: undefined
    _root: ArrayMapNode
        entries: Array[8]
            0: Array[2]
            1: Array[2]
            2: Array[2]
            3: Array[2]
                0: "language"
                1: "ena"
            4: Array[2]
            5: Array[2]
                0: "owners"
                1: List
                    length: 2
                    __proto__: Array[0]
            6: Array[2]
            7: Array[2]

            length: 8
            __proto__: Array[0]
        ownerID: OwnerID
        __proto__: Object
        size: 8
    __proto__: KeyedIterable
```

`entries` is a function. How can I get the value of "**language**" and "**owners**" from this data?

I don't really understand this structure, can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Did you know that it seems that you are using immutable.js? Check its docs https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

Comment: can you show us your Store structure

Comment: @Maxx Thanks! Your answer is exactly what I need. For the 'owners' it returns a List. Can you please tell me how to get the value for that?

Comment: @Sarah same as for `language` - `this.props.rec.get('data').get('owners')`. Then you can get owner by index for example `this.props.rec.get('data').get('owners').get(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know that it seems that you are using immutable.js? Check its docs https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

Try:

```
console.log(this.props.rec.get('data').get('language'))
console.log(this.props.rec.get('data').get('owners').get(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toJS()` to get a more readable version of your data. e.g. `this.props.rec.get('data').toJS()`

Then you could do `this.props.rec.get('data').toJS().owners` to get `owners` or alternatively use the [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/getIn) syntax of `.getIn()` to retrieve the info you need e.g. `this.props.rec.getIn('data', 'owners')`

Comment: Thanks @Geraint, it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This seem like [ES2015 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) problem, and not related to React.

I believe entries has all the key-value pairs for the Map.

Answer (score 0):

We will not get directly as a Map format so we need to convert and fetch data like as below:

```
let postData: any = Map(this.props.data).toJS()   
Object.keys(postData).map((key) => {  
      console.log(postData[key]['attribute'])   
 })
```