# How to access value in immutable object/map in JS?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am trying to grab the 'message' value but it is returning undefined when I use this:

```
console.log('message: ', props.information.getIn(['_root', 'entries']))
```

To console log the data below I use this "console.log(props.information)"

```
size: 4
__altered: false
__hash: undefined
__ownerID: undefined
_root: ArrayMapNode
    entries: Array(4)
        0: (2) ['Name', 'Update']
        1: (2) ['title', 'Update']
        2: (2) ['message', 'Click here to learn about......']
        3: (2) ['clickURL', 'www.google.com']
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I've checked another similar post but I am not understanding.
[Getting value from a map data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699003/getting-value-from-a-map-data-structure)
This question is most similar, but I've tried what they did: 'props.information.get('_root').get('entries')' doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```js
console.log('message: ', props.information.getIn(['entries']));
```

Comment: That returns "undefined"

Comment: This works for me:

const list1 = Map({ entries: [1, 2, 3] });
console.log(getIn(list1, ["entries"]));

Comment: What't the type of props.information? Is it a map?

Comment: yes it is an object

Comment: try `getIn(props.information, ["entries"])`

Comment: are you importing "import {Map} from 'immutable';" or
"import * as Immutable from 'immutable'"? How are you able to use "getIn" as an import? I checked docs.

Comment: `import { Map, getIn } from 'immutable';`

Comment: "Module '"runtime/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable-nonambient"' has no exported member 'getIn'.ts(2305)" yea, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what ended up working for me

```
props.Information.get('message')
```

Comment: Check the [online API docs](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/Map/), they list all available methods. All immutable.js types have `get` and `getIn` methods. Records also allow for direct access to properties like common plain-object